# meteor.js: How to access value of HTML-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

Using the meteor.js framework, how can the value of a HTML element be selected in the "meteor way"? By using a jQuery-selector the browser would iterate through the DOM for every item, which is very expensive, wouldn't it?

The meteor tutorial uses a submit form and handles the template variable in a onSubmit-event. But how is it done if there is no onSubmit (and therefore no template-variable containing the element in question?

Could someone help out with the following example given, please?

**cars.html**

```
<template name="Car">
    <div class="car-item" contenteditable="true">BMW</div>
    <div class="edit-bar"><a href="#" class="save">save</a></div>
</template>
```

**cars.js**

```
'click .save'(event, template){
    //access content of '.car-item' here when '.save' is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [template instance's jQuery](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-$). It will scope only the elements of the current template:

> The template instance serves as the document root for the selector.
>   Only elements inside the template and its sub-templates can match
>   parts of the selector.

This results in a higher performance but requires you to control the granularity and scope of the elements to be searched.

### Example of selector scopes

Just compare the output of the follwing example:

```js
'click .save'(event, templateInstance){
    //access content of '.car-item' here when '.save' is clicked

    // global scope search
    console.log($('div'));

    // template scope search
    console.log(templateInstance.$('div'));
}
```

### Applied to your code

it results in the following code:

```js
'click .save'(event, templateInstance){
    // access content of '.car-item' here when '.save' is clicked
    const carItems = templateInstance.$('.car-item');
    // ... process car items
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding names to your divs

```
<div class="car-item" contenteditable="true" name="car">
```

Then in your click event:

```
click.save(event, template){

   var car = event.target.car.value;
}
```

Let us know if it worked.

Comment: It says the variable "car" is undefined. "event.target" contains only the clicked element: "<a href="#" class="save">save</a>".